# Angular.js stops execution (probably general javascript error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I developed a web portal where users can log in, manage their account stuff, and so on. Technically, it's a JSP/Servlet application running on Tomcat, delivering pages as templates. Each site has an angular app with Controllers, etc. and loads data from JSON-Service (Spring MVC). It's not the classical "single page app" but a "single page per service" app (each page has it's own angular app with sub-views, directives, etc.)

That all works great, but from time to time I'm facing with a strange error, where javascript-execution seems to stop completely (see screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF28q.png). The green ajax-loader should be hidden by angular expression, you see the curly braces in breadcumb navigation and content, success and error-messages appear both, but should be hidden.

After some hours of debugging I found out:

- The error only accurs when javascript-file is minified (I've got a local tomcat running uncompressed and single javascript-files)
- There is absolutely no console.log or so (I'm strictly using $log.info instead)
- There is no javascript-error in console
- It's very hard to get this error in Firefox
- It occurs when user are switching sites (full page refresh) quickly
- It occurs in Internet Explorer 10 when switching compatibility mode/document mode

I followed the angular guidelines for Internet Explorer, so I prefixed all directives with data-*, etc. and I followed the "Note on minification" (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05), so my angular controller/services/directives follow the bracket notation: app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '...', function($scope, ...){}]);

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Florian

Comment: The angular docs warn against minification: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#controller_a-note-on-minification. Here is a tutorial for minsafe angular: http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/

Comment: How you are defining your controller?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. Of course I use the bracket notation from "A note on minification", so my Controller look like     phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {...}]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the angular execution has not even started. Because of the sporadic nature of the error, I would consider some timing problem with the DOM. Do you use RequireJS for async script loading?

Comment: Yes, it's a quite complex application with about 50 single javascript files, no way without require.js

Comment: Did you include the DOMReady Module? http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#domReady

Comment: *facepalm* No...even worse, I read some attributes from DOM before bootstrapping angular (manually). Including domReady solved the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
App.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', ...... ,
  function ($scope, $http, ......) {

}]);
```

you need to use this way to avoid $scope , $http, ... parameters be compressed

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the way I define my controller, services, directives, and so on.